# Formatting a device id for all rows in a dataframe using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to format all the rows in a column to the format "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX" using pandas and failing. (input example: 954E47384F568F91851E1BABE25850XX) Does anyone have an idea of the best way to do this? THANK YOU for your time!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_table('file.txt')

df = df['col1'](lambda x : x[0:8] + '-' + x[9:13] + '-' + x[14:18] + '-' + x[19:23] + '-' + x[23:])
```

I get the error TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable...I know there must be a better way to do this..please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map`

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(lambda x : x[0:8] + '-' + x[9:13] + '-' + x[14:18] + '-' + x[19:23] + '-' + x[23:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.apply()` to apply the function the column.

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x : x[0:8] + '-' + x[9:13] + '-' + x[14:18] + '-' + x[19:23] + '-' + x[23:])
```

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply

Answer (score 0):

try this, you may have to adjust the {} groups to get the ending XX's, i just counted yours from your post to make it:

```
import re
df
#   col1                              col2
#0  Bill  954E47384F568F91851E1BABE25850XX
#1  Will  954E47584F568F91851E1BABE25850XX

df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply((lambda x: '-'.join(map(str,re.search(r'(\w{8})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{8})', x).groups()))))

df
#   col1                              col2
#0  Bill  954E4738-4F56-8F91-851E-1BABE258
#1  Will  954E4758-4F56-8F91-851E-1BABE258
```